# How to send an string from a server (or a client) to all clients in JavaRMI?

Tags: java, rmi, remote-server

I'm using RMI, I have an string obj in my server (or a client) and i want to send it to all clients, how can i do this?

```
public class Myclass extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Server {
    Connection c=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306","root","123");
    String str2="";
    Myclass()throws Exception{
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        Naming.rebind("My Class!!",this);
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    }
    //the override is cause of the interface 'Server'
    @Override
    public String Reciever(String str1) throws Exception {
        str2="Say Hello to "+str1;
        return str2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Myclass mc=new Myclass();
    }
}
```

in this class `str2` will send to that client which is running `Reciever()`, how to send it to all clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RMI servers don't send to clients. They *respond* to clients, when *they* send a *request*, by calling a remote method. The server response is sent as the return value. You will have to have the clients poll the server for these messages, or else make your clients into servers as well.

Answer (score 0):

From the client code, find the service and then request the server object and you can then call remote methods on this class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/client.html

Also why is Reciever() capitalised? It's standard practice for methods to be in camel case (lower case start, upper case for first letter of new words).

Not sure if your server is correct either, you should take a look at this tutorial to ensure you understand how and why RMI works. It's not a long tutorial. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/overview.html

Comment: I have client and my project is so larger than what here is, i just want to find a way to send msg2 to all clients when some client calls Reciever, i'm looking for an easy way...